# Calling 7z from PHP archives wrong items

Tags: php, 7zip

I've been fiddling with this for an hour, haven't figured out why it won't work. I have a project which outputs 3 xlsx and docx files in a temp folder (/temp). I want to zip them for download.

The problem is everytime I exec the 7z command, it zips the whole project folder instead (../temp), not even just the temp folder. I can't figure out why. If I echo `$command` and run it in cmd from PHP's working directory (which shouldn't matter anyway since I use absolute paths for everything), works just fine. It also doesn't work if I use relative paths.

The filename variables `$HSModuleFileName` etc are generated elsewhere, ending in either '.docx' or '.xlsx'

```
$project_dir = str_replace('\\', '/', preg_replace('/\\|\/$/', '', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))) . '/';

$FileName = 'output_' . substr($ImportGUID, -8) . '.zip';


$command = '"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" a -tzip "' . $project_dir . 'temp/' . $FileName . '"
    "' . $project_dir . 'temp/' . $HSModuleFileName . '" "' . $project_dir . 'temp/' . $SummaryFileName . '" "' . $project_dir . 'temp/' . $NoInvoiceFileName . '"';



exec($command);
```

Echo of $command:

```
"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" a -tzip "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/output_38416fc5.zip" "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/HS_Module_38416fc5.xlsx" "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/Summary_38416fc5.xlsx" "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/NoInvoice_38416fc5.docx"
```

So the resulting `output_38416fc5.zip` file actually contains the whole "D:/Projects/JFC" folder

Comment: Did you giving the absolute path of the temp folder?

Comment: Yes, $project_dir gives the absolute path

Comment: Please echo the $command and provide us the output of that echo

Comment: Added the output in the question

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php *With safe mode enabled, the command string is escaped with escapeshellcmd(). Thus, echo y | echo x becomes echo y \| echo x.*

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php it says safe mode has been removed as of PHP 5.4.0, I'm currently on 5.6.3

Comment: I would suggest installing a sysinternals process monitor and check which arguments are actually passed to the 7z

Comment: From what I can see in ProcMon, the command passed to 7z is only "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe"  a -tzip "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/output_de75eb91.zip", the list of files are not passed. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Thanks to @n0rd for pointing me in the right direction. Using sysinternals Process Monitor I saw that on the Process Start event of 7z, the command line parameter was

```
"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" a -tzip "D:/Projects/JFC/temp/output_de75eb91.zip"
```

without the list of files. 
Then I suddenly realized I separated the command with a newline in the PHP code, just before the list of files, which meant it was also processed as a newline by exec.